# Configuring laravel app for production

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, config

everyone. I've recently encountered problems trying to deploy my laravel app to production-like server. So far I've been using it in homestead environment and everything was just fine.

My .env contains something like this:

```
APP_URL=http://public.server.url
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead 
DB_USERNAME=myusername
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

In mysql (running on port 3306) I've set up user 'myusername'@'localhost' with mypassword and indeed I can connect using

```
mysql -u myusername -p
```

Even 'php artisan migrate' command works and modifies my database properly.

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword'),
        //'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Problem is my http controllers don't behave correctly. I am getting 500 server error when sending requests on my routes (no matter how dummy logic they do) and 404 not found when trying to reach non-existing route. Also nothing is appended in the log file. So I am guessing as far as registering routes my app works, but right after that it fails. Any suggestions? I would really appreciate any tips.

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? Have you checked the server's php logs?

Comment: After checking apache error log, I've found, that Apache doesn't have write permissions to storage and bootstrap/cache folder. I granted apache those permissions and voila, problems solved. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! :)